# Event sync failing from Salesforce to Outlook

Tags: salesforce-for-outlook, outlook, lightning-outlook, lightning-for-outlook, salesforce-outlook-sync

Hello all we had a problem with Salesforce to outlook event resync 
I created an event in Salesforce and assigned to outlook contact the event is also displayed in outlook calendar. But when u changed the subject in Salesforce event invite  calendar the changed subject is not reflected in outlook it remains the same the older one which we created first any idea on the same will be very helpful